# Is there any way to disable split screen (view two apps side-by-side) for particular screens/ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, split-screen, split-screen-multitasking

Is there any way to disable/enable split screen (view two apps side-by-side) for particular screens/ViewControllers on ipad?

I am aware of how to do this for the entire application using info.plist. "Requires full screen" option, if this option is set to "YES" it prevents using app in split screen with other app.

I would like to disable split screen for part of an application, for example when for screen/ViewController responsible for watching video (AVPlayer), but remain enabled for other screens.

Comment: Did you find it out?